# Update selected columns in Cassandra table using a batch process without making other column values as null

Tags: java, spring, orm, cassandra, spring-batch

I want to update a table in cassandra using spring batch process which gets the data from some other DB, and want to push it to cassandra.

But the problem is, I am getting 10 columns from that 'other' RDBMS DB and in cassandra table - I have 19 columns, so it updates the 10 common columns and puts 'null' in the remaining 9 columns, but I want to retain the values of those 9 uncommon columns.

I am using ORM for mapping and creating list of ORM objects to push the data. I am also using row mappers to create list of ORM objects. I am also using cassandra template to update the cassandra table

I am getting data from that 'other' DB as chunks of 1000 records

Comment: Do you have some code to show what you are doing?

Comment: I cannot share the code with you, but I can tell that I am using xml files to run the batch process. The xml file calls the 'other' db and gets the data and using java classes i am converting the Please help me with the logic or any function in cassandra  to selectively update the columns in 1 hit

Comment: What is the ORM you use ?

Comment: Object relational Mapping.. it maps every column in cassandra DB to the java variables

Comment: @PrabodhHend did you find the solution for this?